# Why am I getting a Neo4j Cypher parameter Syntax error in neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am getting

> "Expected a parameter named paramEmail"

when I execute the following cypher query in the Neo4j Browser.

```
CREATE (user:Owner {
   email:{paramEmail},
   password:{paramPassword},
   name:{paramName},
   category:{paramCategory}})
RETURN properties(user),
{
   paramEmail: "555@ali.com",
   paramPassword: "5555555",
   paramName: "Tony",
   paramCategory: "Category"
}
```

Based on all my checks this is the correct syntax....what am I missing here....Also, is there a better way to present the parameter?

```
params: {parama:a,paramb:b,paramc:c}
```

didn't work.
 Ok...so I did some more digging an discovered that the syntax in the javascript was actually coming from the .run which I fixed but now I get he same error from the second .then or .catch (invalid token .). Sorry if I seems so basic but I am new to Neo4j especially v3.0 and the Session block is proven a little troublesome. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the block:

```
neo4jSession
        .run ("MATCH (user {email : {paramEmail}}) RETURN count(user)=1 as user_exists",{ paramEmail: newUser.email})

        .then (function(result) {
            console.log("Neo4j Session started");
            if ( result.records[0].get('user_exists') !== true ) 
              {
            neo4jSession
              .run("CREATE (user:Owner {email:{paramEmail}, password:{paramPassword}, name:{paramName}, category:{paramCategory}}) RETURN properties (user)",
                {params: {
                    paramEmail: newUser.email,
                    paramPassword: newUser.password,
                    paramName: newUser.name,
                    paramCategory: newUser.category
                    }})
 //            .run (CREATE (user:newUser.category {email: {newUser.email}, password: {newUser.password}, 
  //                name: {newUser.name}, mobilenumber: {newUser.mobilenumber}) ASSERT newUser.email is UNIQUE RETURN properties (user));

                console.log( result.records[0].get("email") + " " + result.records[0].get("name") );
                neo4jSession.close();
              }
            else   // (found)
             {
               //   email address already exist
                console.log("email address already exist");
                neo4jSession.close();
             }  //end o f else

             //catch any system errors
        .then (function(error)
            {
            neo4jSession.close();   
            console.log(error);
            });
          }) // end of .then
```

Sorry...I think I should also show you guys the db setup..see below:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var neo4jdb = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7474", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"),
     {
          trust: "TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE",
          encrypted:true
     });

var neo4jSession =neo4jdb.session();
```

Finally got rid of the syntax error in the session block by moving around some braces "}" and parens  ")"....still don't quite understand it but I understand the logic....so the code compiled but that section of the  code apparently is not executing!!...the code apparently stopped at the line before the "neo4jSession" right after the "console.log("Neo4j session about to start")...I have included the revised code below:

```
 console.log("Neo4j Session about to start")
//start neo4j session
     neo4jSession
        .run ("MATCH (user {email : {paramEmail}}) RETURN count(user)=1 as user_exists",{ paramEmail: newUser.email})
        .then (function(result) {
            console.log("Neo4j Session started")
            if ( result.records[0].get('user_exists') !== true ) 
              {
            neo4jSession
              .run("CREATE (user:Owner {email:{paramEmail}, password:{paramPassword}, name:{paramName},mobilenumber:{parammobileNumber}, category:{paramCategory}}) RETURN user",
                {params: {
                    paramEmail: newUser.email,
                    paramPassword: newUser.password,
                    paramName: newUser.name,
                    parammobileNumber: newUser.mobilenumber,
                    paramCategory: newUser.category
                    }})
              .then (function(result)
                      {
                         console.log(user.name);
                         neo4jSession.close();  

                     })
              .then (function(error)
                      {
                         neo4jSession.close();  
                         console.log(error);
                     })

 //            .run (CREATE (user:newUser.category {email: {newUser.email}, password: {newUser.password}, 
  //                name: {newUser.name}, mobilenumber: {newUser.mobilenumber}) ASSERT newUser.email is UNIQUE RETURN properties (user));

                console.log( result.records[0].get("email") + " " + result.records[0].get("name") );
                neo4jSession.close();
              }
            else   // (found)
             {
               //   email address already exist
                console.log("email address already exist");
                neo4jSession.close();
             }  //end o f else
            }) // end of .then
             //catch any system errors
        .then (function(error)
            {
            neo4jSession.close();   
            console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: As David says below, parameterized Cypher queries are not supported in the Neo4j Browser. Your comment says you are getting the same error using js as well - can you post the code you are using to execute the query? How are you passing the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Unless something has changed recently that I'm unaware of, parameters aren't supported in the web interface (though they are supported with the neo4j shell, and programmatically).

Comment: Thanks for the response...I am actually getting a similar error in javascript/nodejs..so I tried it in the browser. I will update the question

Comment: You have to match the parameter names of course with what you pass along (in node)

Answer (score 0):

But parameters are supported in neo4j-shell (you'll have to install the zip distribution) in the [cycli](https://github.com/nicolewhite/cycli) client.

just do

`export paramEmail=my@email.com`

And then run your query all shell variables will be passed in as parameters.
You can list them with `env`.

Answer (score 0):

First for clarification, the code for initializing the connection to neo4j database via the [neo4j-driver](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/) for javascript which is used here.

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1
var neo4j_driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost",
                                 neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"),
                                 {
                                    trust: "TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE",
                                    encrypted: true
                                 });

var neo4jSession = neo4j_driver.session();
```

The new user object that should be saved in the database:

```
var newUser = {
   email: "max@somewhere.org",
   password: "s3cr3t",
   name: "Max",
   mobilenumber: "555-12345",
   category: "someCategory"
}
```

A query looks like this

```
session.run(query, [pObject])
.then(resultCallback)
.catch(errorCallback);
```

where `query` is a string (cypher query) and `pObject` is an optional object with keys matching the names in the query string, e.g. `'MATCH (u {name: "Max") RETURN u'` would be with parameters `query = 'MATCH (u {name: { pName }}) RETURN u'` and `pObject = { pName: "Max"}`.

If a result is returned `resultCallback` will be called, on error `errorCallback`.

The function `resultCallback` takes one argument, further called `result`. Then getting a field from the first record is `result.record[0].get('sthing')` where `sthing` is matching a variable in the query `RETURN sthing`. e.g.

```
query = '... RETURN user, object.name, count(sth) as sth_count'
...
// in resultCallback
r = result.record[0]
// right
r.get('user');
r.get('user').name;
r.get('object.name');
r.get('sth_count')
// wrong
r.get('user.name');
r.get('count(sth)');
r.get('sth');
```

The function `errorCallback` takes one argument, further called `error` that contains a description of the occurred error.

`session.close()` should be called, when done with the query in both result and error callback functions.

The adjusted example looks like this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1
var neo4j_driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost",
                                 neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"),
                                 {
                                    trust: "TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE",
                                    encrypted: true
                                 });

var neo4jSession = neo4j_driver.session();

var newUser = {
   email: "max@somewheref.org",
   password: "s3cr3t",
   name: "Max",
   mobilenumber: "555-12345",
   category: "someCategory"
}

//start neo4j session
console.log("Neo4j Session about to start");

neo4jSession.run(
      // query has to be a string 
      "MATCH (user {email : {paramEmail}}) RETURN count(user)=1 as user_exists",
      // parameter Object with keys match those in the query string
      { paramEmail: newUser.email }
   )
   // result callback for outer query
   .then(function(result) {
      console.log("Neo4j Session started");
      console.log(result);
      // parameter to get is the same string as one of the RETURNed variables.
      console.log(result.records[0].get('user_exists')); 

      if (result.records[0].get('user_exists') !== true) {
         neo4jSession.run(
               "CREATE (user:Owner {email:{paramEmail}, password:{paramPassword}, name:{paramName}, mobilenumber:{parammobileNumber}, category:{paramCategory}}) RETURN user", // query has to be a string 
               { // parameter Object with keys match those in the query string
                  paramEmail: newUser.email,
                  paramPassword: newUser.password,
                  paramName: newUser.name,
                  parammobileNumber: newUser.mobilenumber,
                  paramCategory: newUser.category
               }                                   
            )
            // result callback for inner query
            .then(function(result) { // for results use .then(...)
               // parameter to get is the same string as one of the RETURNed variables. 
               console.log("New user" + result.records[0].get("user")); 

               neo4jSession.close();
            })
            .catch(function(error) { //for errors use .catch(...)
               console.log("Inner query error");
               console.log(error);
               neo4jSession.close();
            })
      } else // (found)
      {
         // email address already exist
         console.log("email address already exist");
      } // end of else
      neo4jSession.close();
   }) // end of .then

   //catch any system errors of outer query
   .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Outer query error");
      console.log(error);
      neo4jSession.close();
   });
```

P.S.: The `newUser` Object could be used directly as query parameter object, only the variable names in the query string had to be adjusted to match the keys of `newUser`. You could even pass the `newUser` object and use the keys as property names and values as values like so:

```
query = "CREATE (user:Owner {params}) RETURN user";
pObject = {params: newUser};
session.run(query, pObject).then(...).catch(...);
```